# PUT on REST collection. Do I provide addresses?

Tags: rest, restful-architecture

When you do a PUT on a REST collection should you provide the addresses of the members in the collection?

PUT on dogs with address specified

```
[{"name":"sparky", "id":1}, {"name":"rusty", "id":2}]
```

or...

PUT on dogs without address specified

```
[{"name":"sparky"}, {"name":"rusty"}]
```

and let the server return the locations of the new members in the collection. In my case the row ids in my table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sending a `PUT` to replace every resource in the entire collection, you should send the full new / updated entities.

- If the `id` is part of the entity, you should send it within the entity, but for the client that has nothing to do with the URI (a.k.a the "address") of the element, as **clients have now knowledge how a URI is build** by the server.
- If the `id` is not part of the entity for the client, you should not send it within the entity.

But both cases are possible and your server could accept both, important is just that the the `PUT` on collection behaves as in the [HTTP/1.1 specs](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.6) described:

> The PUT method requests that the enclosed entity be stored under the supplied Request-URI.

So if you `PUT` on `/api/animals/dogs/` the dogs just be found under `/dogs/` and not e.g. `/cats/`

> If the Request-URI refers to an already existing resource, the enclosed entity SHOULD be considered as a modified version of the one residing on the origin server

That means that a `PUT` on any collection, delectes the whole collection and creates a new one with the entities given in the body of the method call.

> If the Request-URI does not point to an existing resource [...] the origin server can create the resource with that URI.

That means if `/animals/dogs/` is empty you should create a new collection there.

Comment: Hey, thanks for responding. Yea I am a little lost in all this. My understanding is pretty solid on GET, POST, and DELETE for REST, but I find it hard to deal with what a PUT on a collection does. According to this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer (I know wikipedia...) A PUT would replace the collection, which is what I was attempting to do in my question. Is there no PUT on collections at all?

Comment: Hi, sorry that was not correct. `PUT` on collection is indeed possible, but I have not seen it in a real world environment. For me `DELETE` on the collection and then `POST` feels much better, but there is no technical explanation for that so I have updated my answer to deal with your wanted case.